# AWS Amplify GraphQL Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'ID!'

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I have this graphql query to create a new item. This query has worked for months, then I left the app for a while, and suddenly it doesn't work now. It gives me the error above which is off for a creation request as it should create the ID.

Error:

```
Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'ID!'
```

Code:

```
  const addArticle = async (event) => {
    const input = { ...article, data: JSON.stringify(article.data) };
    return await API.graphql({
      query: createArticle,
      variables: { input: input },
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
  };
```

GraphQL:

```
type Article
  @model
  @key(name: "byTag", fields: ["tagId", "dateWritten"])
  @key(name: "bySource", fields: ["sourceId", "dateWritten"]) {
  id: ID!
  link: AWSURL!
  title: String!
  dateWritten: String!
  articleDate: AWSDateTime
  data: AWSJSON!
  approved: Boolean!
  admin: Boolean!
  tagId: ID!
  creatorId: ID!
  creator: User @connection(fields: ["creatorId"])
  sourceId: ID!
  source: Source @connection(fields: ["sourceId"])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured out that the problem with the query was that a separate property (which was required) had not been filled and was null. This caused the query not to work.

So, it's just a bad error message.